# I want to show the whole c program on screen in android

Tags: android

I wanted to show the whole c program on screen which should be visible to user.

I used textView but i am getting errors as the code contains special symbols.

for example:

```
 android:text=" #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
{
int x, y, temp;

printf("Enter the value of x and y\n");
scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);

printf("Before Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n",x,y);

temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;

printf("After Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n",x,y);

return 0;
 }" />
```

I also want that the user should be able to scroll the code as the codes may be larger than the example.I am a noob so please suggest me any alternate for the textView to display the code.

Comment: one way to do it is to [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the special chars in the input, and encase the textview in a scrollview.

Comment: the special character " cannot be escaped as it is important part to display .

Comment: @ashwinbhy in the XML layout file you can escape the " character with `&quot;`, other special characters are <, >, & which can be escaped by `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;` respectively. The TextView will then display the characters correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your C code in a file in assets folder, for example "res/assets/code.c".

Write a function that reads the content of a file to a String:

```
private String readFileInAssetsDir(String filename) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(filename)));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line + "\n");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // TODO
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And now define a WebView (not a TextView) in your layout (the advantages are that you can show any character, and WebView provides zoom and scroll directly):

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

And finally  I would enclose all C code in a `<pre></pre>` tag and then show it inside the WebView widget:

```
    String plainCode = readFileInAssetsDir("code.c");
    String htmlCode = "<pre>" + plainCode + "</pre>";
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlCode, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Comment: i am a noob in this buddy.
Can you explain me with the example program which i posted.

Would appreciate your help.


Or can it be done by placing a txt file for the code in raw folder
and displaying the contents somehow on the xml.

Comment: Bro this wont work as the string is closed by " 
and the code contains " in it it gives an error that the string is not closed properly

Comment: It didn't work because Java doesn't support multiline strings. I have edited my answer (and actually tested for the first time). Check it.

Comment: THis was not working up.
I made the following changes :
          `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/code.c");`

Comment: Why? It works for me... Your different approach is of course much shorter, but in order to be organised you should NOT save HTML syntax representing the C code in your assets folder, just your C code, and include <pre> tags later in your Activity code... Anyway, if everything is solved and you took advantage of the WebView/<pre> tag idea, you should mark my answer as correct;-)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THIS WORKS BUT READS ONLY A SINGLE LINE OF THE TEXT IN THE TXT FILE

String line;
TextView view;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addingprogrammultipletimes);

    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open("add.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        line = reader.readLine();
        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        view.setText(line);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```