# Android : Multi-Line Text View

Tags: android, textview

I am building an app that include the c++ programs. I just need to show the code as a text in my xml layout. I don't want it to compile it or to do anything else with it. But every time i write the text it show error that you cant use strings like '<', '>' or double inverted commas. Can you please help me out how i can use these strings in my text view. 
Here is my xm layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/program_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="
       #include<iostream.h>
       #include<conio.h>
       void main()
       {
         int arr[n], i,j,n,temp;
         cout<<"How any elements you want to enter";
         cin>>n;
         cout<<"Enter array elements"
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
         cin>>a[i]
       }     " >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to my response in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340104/i-want-to-show-the-whole-c-program-on-screen-in-android/14340202). You shouldn't include literal strings in your XML layout. It is much more recommended to store C code in files in assets folder, so you don't need to modify them at all (it's a waste of time and a source of errors). Just inflate a WebView widget with all the C code enclosed in `<pre>[text read from file]</pre>` tags and you will be able to show it perfectly OK and take advantage of scrolling and zoom for free.

Comment: can you please explain me a little about this. Thnx in advance.

Comment: Take a look to my response in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340104/i-want-to-show-the-whole-c-program-on-screen-in-android/14340202. I provide a code example there.

Comment: But there is no asset folder in my res.
Moreover i am not able to understand that <pre> tag part.

Comment: Just create that folder and put your files with C code in it. In HTML, a `<pre>` tag means that any text you enclose inside will be showed without any parsing, so special symbols like quotes, <, >, and the rest won't bother you any more. For me, it's by far the best solution.

Comment: It could look like a trick to someone, but is not. It's just organisation. You store files with C code, without making any change on them (since it has no sense to do any change on them just to show them). Then you make use of a WebView widget where you can show any HTML code you want. Then, you make use of a <pre> tag with all C code inside it. It's exactly the same a good web designer would do in a webpage. It's the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Thanx. I think its the best way to organise all my c++ code. I will try it your way. Hope its works. If i get any error, i will ask you.. Thanx again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Try it and you will find a lot of advantages, trust me:-)

Comment: As my app contains a lot of c++ program code. so i need to store a separate file for each one or all programs can be stored in one.?
and do i need a text file to store all programs ?

Comment: I would store each C++ program in a different text file, specially if you want to show only one program at a time in the WebView. I don't know your particular requeriments, but you could do it in many different ways

Answer (score 3):

Try this for xml special characters.

```
 < replace into &lt; 
 >  replace into &gt;
 " replace into &quot;
```

you need any other special characters code for xml see this
link:http://www.quackit.com/html/html_special_characters.cfm

Comment: sorry. But i didnt get what are you trying to say. please explain.

Comment: #include&ltiostream.h&gt etc. You can also put your text in strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can do as suggested by Tamilarasi or there's a trick to do that automatically.
Just replace your " " with ' ' and hit CTRL+SHIFT+ F . Eclipse will automatically make those changes for you.

```
android:text='
       #include<iostream.h>
       #include<conio.h>
       void main()
       {
         int arr[n], i,j,n,temp;
         cout<<"How any elements you want to enter";
         cin>>n;
         cout<<"Enter array elements"
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
         cin>>a[i]
       }     '>
```

Comment: thnxx thnxxx a lottt dude!
i was trying to do it for a long time! love youu mahn!

Comment: one last thing. How can i set the gravity for each line as c++ is not properly displying in the graphical layout. code seems to be scattered.

Comment: Did you tried over a device or saying it by looking at the graphical layout of your xml file?

Comment: i am saying by just looking at the xml layout.

Comment: sorry it just happened. i don't know how.

Comment: give a \n inside that text of your textview from wherever you want to start a new line

Comment: should i am required to write \n before the start of every new line?
well i just tried that and instead it shows \n in my text layout.